# How do I use PNGs to mask the edges of an image?

Tags: html, css, image, png, masking

I've used border-image with PNGs to create rough borders but I'm wondering if there is there a way to mask in a similar way?

http://www.rumchata.com/

Rumchata does what I'm looking for. The blue gif in the background has rough edges. I assume they're using PNG textures to mask the edges of the gif.
Does anyone know how?

Comment: it's not a gif, it's a video. just for fun: https://jsfiddle.net/tLxexgw6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask-image` and `-webkit-mask-image` to mask in the way they've done. I've put together a simple example below, with a picture of palm trees and a star. You can do this with a video instead if you want to.

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/A_Black_Star.png);
  mask-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/A_Black_Star.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="http://polyadhawaiitours.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/PalmTree1.jpg">
</body>
```